# Sharing a class between two Visual Studio projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I was looking for some help with sharing classes between 2 seperate projects in VS2012.

I have added a new project called TaxiRouteModel and added a reference to it from my 2 other projects in the solution. Which seems to work just great. I no longer have to maintain 2 separate projects.

But the class library which is shared by both web projects will never be published to the website and the 2 web projects are published to 2 separate places.

Once the websites have been published will they still be able to reference the class library?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When the web sites are compiled, the DLL is copied from the library project to the `bin` folder of the web site project, so when the web site is published it will also have the DLL from the library project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as the DLL is available in the bin folder